# Can't boot into Ubuntu after fresh dual boot instalation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I'm using Windows 10 and decided to install ubuntu for developing only.
The problem is: I can't reach even the login screen.

I did a few different fresh installations so I could get the Grub working. Now I can see Grub and pick Ubuntu or Windows, but when I try ubuntu I get errors.
If I go to "Ubuntu Advanced options" it shows me 2 different versions too (both errors).

Already:

- Tried to uninstall Nvidia-* drivers through "recovery mode";
- Turned off Fast Boot/ CMS/ Rapid whatever~;
- Installed as UEFI using Rufus;

The screen gets frozen as the image shows.
[image: Photo of the Errors]

Comment: what is the last message? can't read all of it from the screenshot. It looks like it's trying to do a disk scan? That usually takes time, so maybe it's not stuck, just running that long operation?

Comment: It says to "press CTRL+C to CANCEL all verification on folders" but it DOES NOT WORK. THe screen is freezed and the keyboard doesn't work.